# What's the point of using client certificate if mysql server doesn't verify the clients?

Tags: mysql

By default mysql server creates these 6 certificates in `/var/mysql/lib`:

```
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1676 Aug  3 00:16 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1112 Aug  3 00:16 ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1112 Aug  3 00:16 client-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1676 Aug  3 00:16 client-key.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1680 Aug  3 00:16 private_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql  452 Aug  3 00:16 public_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  1172 Aug  6 12:20 server-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1676 Aug  3 00:16 server-key.pem
```

As mentioned in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/creating-ssl-rsa-files-using-mysql.html , `public_key.pem` and `private_key.pem` are used in:

> These key-pair files enable secure password exchange using RSA over unencrypted connections for accounts authenticated by the `sha256_password` plugin;

If I understand correctly, the other 6 certificates are used for mutual tls verification.

I tested it with DataGrip and there are 3 options: `Require`, `Verifa CA` and `Full Verification`. (commandline interface e.g. `mysqlsh` has corresponding options)

- `Require` has nothing to with certificates, it starts a tls encryption with server as ordinary https does.
- `Verify CA` verifies the `ca.pem`, which you get from the server `/var/lib/ca.pem`.
- `Full Verification` is the client verifying not only the `ca.pem`, but also `server-cert.pem` and `server-key.pem`.
  ( you need to re-generate a `server-cert.pem` for this work. Because the auto-generated `server-cert.pem` 's `Subject:` field doesn't match the server ip/domain)

[image]

None of the options reuire specifying client cert and key. So what's the usage of proving `client-key.pem` and `client-cert.pem` in the client? I don't find an option like "verify the client" in mysql server. So it's merely one way verification and client certs are completely useless? I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have missed this in the documentation: when you create a user, you can specify various [TLS authentication options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html#create-user-tls). For example,

```
CREATE USER 'rick'@'%' REQUIRE SUBJECT 'CN=Rick' AND ISSUER '...'
```

Comment: Yes, the linked documentaion explains how client certs work. I tried `CREATE USER 'rick'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' require X509;`   in the `X509` section and had some experiments with my client. It matches my expectation. Thanks!